# First column header in a javascript CSV download not being included when downloaded in chrome

Tags: javascript

I've got a javascript function that is responsible for downloading data into a csv based on some checked fields and ordering coming from a database. However, in chrome the first column header is not included in the output. In the browser console I can see that all headers are included in the initial export data

The column data is there, and all headers are shifted one to the left, when downloaded in IE the headers are correct. I have opened the CSVs in notepad and they have no corruption or bad data, this issue is also not specific to any one header, no matter what order the data is in, the first column header will not be in the output if the download is in chrome

This is the function handling the download

```
 function downloadCSV(args) {
            //console.log('markers: ', markers)
                var arrData = [];
                var checkedFields = [];
                //gets checked boxes
                const detailBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=detailsCheckbox]:checked')

                for (i = 0; i < detailBoxes.length; i++) {
                    //gets id of checked boxes
                    checkedFields.push(detailBoxes[i].id)
            }

            "use strict";
              var arrExportMod = []
                  var modelDataForExport = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.exportModel) as String);
               // console.log('modelDataForExport: ', modelDataForExport)
           for (i = 0; i <@Model.exportModel.Count; i++) {

                var expObj = {
                    name: modelDataForExport[i].Field_Name,
                    ordinal: modelDataForExport[i].Export_Order      //this is for the custom export ordering
                }
                arrExportMod.push(expObj)
                }

   
            arrExportMod.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
          //  console.log('arrExportMod: ', arrExportMod)

            var names = []

            for (i = 0; i < arrExportMod.length; i++) {
                names.push(arrExportMod[i].name)
            }

            
         //   console.log('names: ', names)

   names = names.filter(function(item){
  if ( checkedFields.indexOf(item) !== -1 ) return item;
});    
        //    console.log('checkedFields: ', checkedFields)


            for (i = 0; i < goodMarkers.length; i++) {

                    var details = {};

               // console.log('checkedFields: ', checkedFields.length)
                   for (j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
                       var fieldName = names[j]
                  //     console.log('fieldName: ', fieldName)
                   //    console.log(' goodMarkers' + [i] + 'fieldName: ',  goodMarkers[i][fieldName])
                       details[fieldName] = '"' + goodMarkers[i][fieldName] + '"';

                   }
                    arrData.push(details);

            }


          //  arrData = arrExportMod.filter(v => arrData.includes(v));
   //         console.log('details: ', details)
           // console.log('indicudia: ', goodMarkers[0]['headlineRate'])
         //   console.log('arrData: ', arrData)

                var data, filename, link;
                //get csv created
                var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                    data: arrData
                });
                if (csv == null) return;

            filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

            if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8' + '\n' + csv;
            }
            data = encodeURI(csv);
            console.log('csv before download: ', csv)
            console.log('data before download: ', data)
            //download csv in browser
            var BOM = "\uFEFF";
            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { //this if statement is only entered if the browser is IE and is //the only difference between chrome and IE downloads
                // ie block

            var blobObject = new Blob([BOM + csv], { type: ' type: "text/csv; charset=utf-8"' });

            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, filename);
        }
        //    console.log('data: ', data)
                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                link.click();
            }
```

This is the function for the csv creation

```
 function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
            var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

            //if data is empty return nothing
            data = args.data || null;
            if (data == null || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }
     //       console.log('export data: ', data)
            //sets as comma delimited if not specified
            columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
            lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

            keys = Object.keys(data[0]);


            console.log('data: ', data)

            result = '';
            result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
            result += lineDelimiter;

            //loops through data and writes to file
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                ctr = 0;
                keys.forEach(function (key) {
                  //  console.log('key: ', key)
                    if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

                    result += item[key];

                    ctr++;
                });
                result += lineDelimiter;
            });
          //    console.log('result: ', result)
            return result;
        }
```

Does anyone know why the first column header would be missing in chrome but not in IE?